# How to remove style binding based on screen height media query (by condition) in Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The component has the following binding:

```
 <div
    class="columns dropdowns"
    :style="{
      height: `${dropdownsgridheight}px`,
    }"
  >
```

That height is getting calculated based on count of dropdowns. On mobile screens, it shows poorly. So I need to remove this style binding when screen height is less than 812px. How can it be done correctly in Vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div
  class="columns dropdowns"
  :style="finalHeight"
 ></div>
```

and in your component:

```
data() {
  return {
      finalHeight: ''
  }
},
created() {
   window.addEventListener("resize", this.myEventHandler);
},
destroyed() {
   window.removeEventListener("resize", this.myEventHandler);
},
methods: {
  myEventHandler() {
    if(window.innerHeight > 812) {
       this.finalHeight = {
          "height": this.dropdownsgridheight + 'px'
       }
    }
    else {
       this.finalHeight = '15px'
    }
  },
},
computed: {
  dropdownsgridheight () {
         return '50'
    }
},
mounted() {
   this.myEventHandler()
}
```

here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/Nanif/yvw2h5pe/1/

Comment: What about event listeners? I assume created and beforedestroy should be used as well for cleaning the resizing.

Comment: dropdownsgridheight is getting calculated inside computed so you syggest to use one inside another and both in computed?

Comment: When I resize the screen I have to refresh to see the result with your solution

Comment: You can call `dropdownsgridheight ` from your dom like this: `:style="dropdownsgridheight`, and simply wrap the return object with condition like in my answer.

Comment: I mean I tried your answer and each time when I resize I also do a refresh to see a results because it doesn't do autocmatically.

Comment: And both functions are inside computed

Comment: Dropdownheight was a function that calculated height

Comment: The idea is to have binding. in case you have it by using `event listener` you can use your dropdownsgridheight as a function and call it from `EventHandler()`. acording to the result of dropdown height - you should set a variable in `data` that style is binding to it. (:style="<someProperty>")

Comment: this.dropdownsgridheight = {
             "height": this.dropdownsgridheight + 'px'
          }

This part is confusing dropdownsgridheight which one should be replaced with my function and which one is variable you set 2 things  with the same

Comment: Look again in the answer, I just add it.

Comment: Nope. To be honest the first solution worked better. Tho only thing was needed there resizing part because this one is not working at all

Comment: OK, Sorry for driving you crazy. I run the code and find the problem(s).
1. in the html. you should bind style to `finalHeight`
2. add else to `myEventHandler`. look at the answer....

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Nanif/yvw2h5pe/1/ an example for you.

Comment: @Dave I add the code here, so you can see the whole flow.  
  https://jsfiddle.net/Nanif/yvw2h5pe/1/  goodluck

Comment: Thanks, I will check. Will it work if the component will be placed inside parent page?